# Get value from radio button PHP

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I am making a form where you can choose whether you wanna be anonymous or not via a radio button, however, I cannot get it to work.

This is my HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" name="anonym" value="ja" />Ja
<input type="radio" name="anonym" value="nei" checked/>Nei
```

PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['snd_skjema'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form

  if($_POST['anonym'] == 'ja') {
    $anonym = $id;

  } elseif($_POST['anonym'] == 'nei') {
    $anonym = NULL;
  }
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: there's code missing here, as in the form tags. How do we know if you're using the proper method?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['snd_skjema'])) {...}` we don't know if that happens or not; does it? and is missing a brace for it.

Comment: please add up your complete from so one could be able to help! also please add an ending bracket to `if (isset($_POST['snd_skjema'])) {`

Comment: asking for more code shouldn't be like pulling teeth; I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

To see witch one is selected just check if it holds data.

like this

```
if (isset($_POST['snd_skjema'])) {

  if($_POST['anonym']) {
     $anonym = $id;

  } else {
    $anonym = NULL;
 }
```

Comment: What was your purpose in writing this answer?

Answer (score 0):

in your php i don't see you inicializing your id and anonym variables
try this below

html

```
<input type="radio" name="anonym" value="ja" />Ja
<input type="radio" name="anonym" value="nei" checked/>Nei
```

php

```
//making sure reqquest method is post 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 $anonym_err = ""; $anonym = ""; $id = "";

/*verify that your anonym $_POST value is not empty first 
it could be the reason it does not work
if it is empty the anonym error variable picks an error*/

    if (empty($_POST["anonym"])) {
        $anonym_err = "choose an anonym type";
      } else {
        if($_POST["anonym"] == "ja"){
      $anonym = $id;
    }elseif($_POST["anonym"] == "nei"){
    $anonym = NULL;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: i inicialized  the $id variable an gave it an empty value if you use this make sure you inicialise the id variable with the value your wish to use